# Eine Alternative zum Verb "erweitern"

Tags: synonym

Ich habe mich gefragt, was die Alternative zur Tunwort `erweitern` ist.
In einem Internetwörterbuch habe ich wieder zwei passende Tätigkeitswörter dafür gefunden, nämlich :

> vergrößern
>
> verbreitern

Ich möchte es in diesem Zusammenhang sagen :

> I would like to broaden my vocabulary.

Kann ich die beiden in diesem Kontext  benutzen :

> Ich möchte gern mein Vokabular vergrößern.
>
> Ich möchte gern meinen Wortschatz verbreitern.

Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt viele Synonyme zu *erweitern*. In diesem Kontext würde ich aber zu genau diesem greifen.

Wenn du echt ein anderes Wort verwenden möchtest (um zum Beispiel Wiederholung zu vermeiden), würde ich zu *aufstocken* greifen. Eventuell auch *ausdehnen* oder *ausweiten*.

Gegebenenfalls wäre auch eine Umformulierung in Betracht zu ziehen, zum Beispiel:

> mehr Wörter in mein Vokabular *aufnehmen*/*übernehmen*

Aber nochmals: Das Wort schlechthin in dem Kontext ist *erweitern*.

Answer (score 3):

In Duden – *Das Synonymwörterbuch* werden einige Synonyme für *erweitern* aufgeführt.

> **erweitern**
>
> anbauen, aufstocken, ausbauen, ausdehnen, ausgestalten, ausweiten, bereichern, ergänzen, hinzufügen, hinzutun, verbreitern, vermehren, vergrößern, verstärken, weitern; *(bildungssprachlich):* amplifizieren; *(veraltet):* extendieren; *(Fachsprache):* dilatieren; *(Politik, Wirtschaft):* expandieren.

Synonyme sind Wörter mit gleicher oder sehr ähnlicher Bedeutung, sodass sie in einem bestimmten Zusammenhang ausgetauscht werden können. Wirklich bedeutungsgleiche Wörter sind selten. In dem durch die Beispiele

> Ich möchte gern mein Vokabular *erweitern.*
> Ich möchte gern meinen Wortschatz *erweitern.*

gegebenen Zusammenhang sind beispielsweise die folgenden Synonyme anwendbar (die Erklärungen der Bedeutung stammen aus Duden – *Deutsches Universalwörterbuch*):

> **erweitern**
> **1.** *in seiner Ausdehnung, in seinem Umfang vergrößern*
>
> **aufstocken**
> **2.** *etwas um eine bestimmte größere Menge, Anzahl o. Ä. vermehren, erweitern*
>
> **ausbauen**
> **2.** *erweitern, vergrößern, [weiter] ausgestalten*
>
> **bereichern**
> **1. a)** *reichhaltiger machen; vergrößern, erweitern*
>
> **ergänzen**
> **1. a)** *durch Schließen entstandener Lücken wieder vollständig machen; durch Hinzufügen von etwas vervollständigen, bereichern*
>
> **vergrößern**
> **1. a)** *in seiner Ausdehnung, seinem Umfang größer machen; erweitern*

Answer (score 1):

Am häufigsten würden wohl folgende Möglichkeiten verwendet werden:

> 1. Ich möchte meinen Wortschatz erweitern.
> 2. Ich möchte meinen Wortschatz ausbauen.

Vorstellbar wäre auch Folgendes:

> Ich möchte meinen Wortschatz verbessern.

Während *verbessern* nicht unbedingt ein Synonym für *erweitern* ist, bedeutet es in diesem Kontext mehr oder weniger dasselbe.

Die folgenden, von dir genannten, Versionen würden im Sprachgebrauch in diesem Kontext nicht verwendet werden:

- "Ich möchte gern mein Vokabular ergrößern."

  Möglich wäre zwar *vergrößern*, wobei auch das in diesem Kontext eher selten verwendet werden würde.
- "Ich möchte gern meinen Wortschatz verbreitern."

  *Verbreitern* ist in diesem Kontext ebenfalls nicht korrekt.
  Verbreitern würde beispielsweise in folgendem Satz gut passen:

  > Die Straße war nicht breit genug, deshalb musste sie verbreitert werden.